# Change sort order and add paging for search results

Tags: feature-request, documentation, search

When I perform a search like https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=c%23&query=exception to get documentation about Exceptions in C# the results are ordered by something I cannot determine. At least do the top results do not contain anything about Exceptions.

I expected to get as Top result the documentation about [Exception Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/46/exception-filters#t=201607220527007695564). But it is even not on the first result page.

It would be nice when the search results are ordered by score, to get the top documentations to a search query.

Also paging through the search results is missing